# Flash Action Script 3: how to get hex value from a color picker?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

this is my code.

```
dropColor.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, updateValue);
function updateValue(e:ColorPickerEvent){
    trace(dropColor.hexValue);
}
```

It doesn't work.

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ColorPickerEvent.
```

Could someone tell me why?

Comment: what line is the error on? I don't want to create a new project for this..

Comment: but you can try this for start: 2function updateValue(e:Object){" in the second line

Answer (score 5):

You need to add an import for your ColorPickEvent.

```
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;
```

Also, depending on which compiler you are using, you most likely need the fl.swc :

http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2007/10/30/tips-n-tricks/fl-package-swc/

You'll need to add that to your project, follow the directions on that page.